# Is there a way to predict where a Rigidbody will go with walls and other moving rigidbodies?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on an air hockey game, and I need the AI to predict where the ball is going to go so it can hit it, instead of just chasing after it. The problem is that the AI can't predict the wall that it and the puck will hit, and it's predictions go like this:

[image]

Here's the code I'm using right now:

```
if(isEnemy) {
     if(puck.transform.position.z >= 0) {
          transformToLookAt = (puck.transform.position + (puck.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity * timeToHit));
          transform.LookAt(transformToLookAt);
          rb.AddForce(transform.forward * step);
     } else {
          transformToLookAt = new Vector3(0f, 10.5f, 175f);
          transform.LookAt(transformToLookAt);
          rb.AddForce(transform.forward * step);
     }
} else {
    if(puck.transform.position.z <= 0) {
          transformToLookAt = (puck.transform.position + (puck.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity*timeToHit));                    
          transform.LookAt(transformToLookAt);
          rb.AddForce(transform.forward * step);
    } else {
          transformToLookAt = new Vector3(0f, 10.5f, -175f);
          transform.LookAt(transformToLookAt);
          rb.AddForce(transform.forward * step);
    }
}
```

**Note: Step is the speed, declared above this code, and the timeToHit is if it should predict the position of the puck in 3 seconds, 2 seconds, etc.(Set to 0.5f currently)**

If the puck is on the opposite side of the striker, it goes to a position I hardcoded, otherwise it will just keep chasing the puck and slamming the invisible wall. (That's what the `if(isEnemy)` is for. I use it so the striker only chases the puck while it is on the striker's side)

How would I have it predict the bounce? There will also sometimes be other pucks (2v2, 3v3, etc.); would I be able to predict those bounces as well?

**Edit: derHugo's code is pretty much all you need, but it does come with some bugs that I fixed and thought would be important to show.**

Here is the code:

```
public Vector3 GetPredictedPosition(Rigidbody puck, float predictionTime)
{ 
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        return GetHitOrEndPosition(puck.position, puck.velocity, step * predictionTime);
}

private Vector3 GetHitOrEndPosition(Vector3 startPoint, Vector3 direction, float maxDistance)
{
        // Instantiate a RaycastHit. This will have all the accessible attributes we will need, such as hit.normal, hit.distance, etc.
        RaycastHit hit;

        // Did you hit something?
        // The problem before was that Physics.Raycast shoots out a raycast, but does not return the RaycastHit data type. It instead returns a bool of whether it hit any colliders or not.
        // However, if we set the 3rd argument(this is important, it didn't work as the other arguments), with the *out* keyword, it will essentially return the bool to the if statement
        // and it will return the RaycastHit data to the hit variable we declared above.
        if(Physics.Raycast(startPoint, direction, out hit, maxDistance)) 
        {
            // Now, we can use the rest of the code as usual
            // Reflect the direction on the hit surface normal
            var reflectedDirection = Vector3.Reflect(direction, hit.normal);
            // Reduce the distance by the so far covered raycas distance
            var reducedDistance = maxDistance - hit.distance;          

            // Shoot a new Raycast from that hitpoint into the new reflected direction and the new reduced distance (and go back to 2.)
            return GetHitOrEndPosition(hit.point, reflectedDirection, reducedDistance);
        }
    
        // At the tip of the last shot ray (startPoint + direction * maxDistance) there is your predicted position.
        return startPoint + direction * maxDistance;
}
```

Comment: You can use `Physics.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime)` to determine where an object will be on the next physics update.  These two resources should be helpful: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Simulate.html and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnhfcdtGM2E

Comment: @HumanWrites no you can't ^^ at least not that simple .. OP is asking for a prediction of e.g. "Where will the objects be in XY seconds?" ... `Physics.Simulate` doesn't help at all for predictions .. it is not predicting the positions but is rather actually executing the entire physics engine "manually" ... Now you **could** kinda use that, store all current positions, velocities etc, then simulate e.g. the next 30 frames, check where the puck is now, then reset everything to thee preciously stored values .. doing this each frame would be pretty expensive though ;)

Comment: I mean, that's pretty much what I was suggesting.  You only need to predict on FixedUpdate frames so you can ignore it for other frames.  You can further reduce the need to similate and reset by raycasting against colliders ahead of the puck to estimate whether it will hit another physics object in the next FixedUpdate and ignore it otherwise.  Based on the description of OPs use case, it seems like a feasible solution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could at least **roughly estimate** it and assume the puck travels with **linear speed** (you current code also makes this assumption anyway) and assume **other targets do not move** (like e.g. walls but also other players).

Then you could simply do something like

1. shoot a [`Physics2D.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) from the current position and direction with max distance of `currentSpeed * predictionTime`
2. Did you hit something?

   1. **YES**

      1. [`Vector2.Reflect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Reflect.html) the Raycast direction
      2. reduce the distance by the so far traveled distance
      3. shoot a new Raycast from that hitpoint into the new reflected direction and the new reduced distance (and go back to 2.)
   2. **NO** => at the tip of the last shot ray

      ```c#
      startPoint + direction * maxDistance
      ```

   there is your predicted position.

So in code this might look somewhat like e.g.

```c#
public Vector2 GetPredictedPosition(Rigidbody2D puck, LayerMask layers, float predictionTime)
{ 
    return GetHitOrEndPosition(puck.position, puck.velocity, currentLinearSpeed.magnitude * predictionTime, layers);
}

private Vector2 GetHitOrEndPosition(Vector2 startPoint, Vector2 direction, float maxDistance, LayerMask layers)
{
    // 1. Shoot raycast from current position and direction with max distance of currentSpeed * predictionTime
    var hit = Physics2D.Raycast(startPoint, direction, maxDistance, layers);

    // 2. Did you hit something?
    if(hit.collider) 
    {
        // 2.1. YES

        // 2.1.1. Reflect the direction on the hit surface normal
        var reflectedDirection = Vector2D.Reflect(direction, hit.normal);
        // 2.1.2. reduce the distance by the so far covered raycas distance
        var reducedDistance = maxDistance - hit.distance;          

        // 2.1.3 shoot a new Raycast from that hitpoint into the new reflected direction and the new reduced distance (and go back to 2.)
        return GetHitOrEndPosition(hit.point, reflectedDirection, reducedDistance, layers);
    }
   
    // 2.2 NO
    // => at the tip of the last shot ray (startPoint + direction * maxDistance) there is your predicted position.
    return startPoint + direction * maxDistance;
}
```

Now how often you pull this prediction point is up to you and of course

---

And as mentioned you **could** also additionally [`Physics2D.Simulate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Simulate.html) and predict the player movement in order to be more precise for moving colliders. That is very expensive though and probably not that necessary .. depending on your target AI level of course.

I mean you could even throw some machine learning in there and let your AI learn where to go for certain puck position and velocity patterns, so basically you can go from here as complex as you like ;)